# Exception handling in .NET Core API consuming WCF Service

Tags: c#, api, wcf, .net-core

Im creating API in .NET Core, which consumes WCF Service. Accessing WCF service is realised, by calling any method, getting an exception (Access denied), and than calling LogIn method using cookie returned in header with first call response. Than, after login i want to retry my original call. All exceptions are the same, and only message string is different. Here is my code for one method call:

```
public async Task<List<scheduleElement>> getSchedule(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    bool secondTry = false;

    while (true)
    {

        try
        {

            var data = await _scheduleServiceClient.getScheduleAsync(start, end);

            if (data.@return == null) return new List<scheduleElement>();

            return data.@return.ToList();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            
            if (!secondTry && e.Message.StartsWith("Access denied for WebService method:"))
            {
                
                var logged = await LogIntoSOAPServices();
                if (!logged) throw;

            }
            else throw;

            secondTry = true;

        }

    }

}
```

Im using proxies generated with WCF Web Service Reference Provider

This works, but Im looking for a way to globaly handle exceptions and retry logic like this, because im going to have to copy and paste tons of code. I have Exception handler in my API but if i catch this exceptions with it im not able to retry method i originaly called.

Comment: Why not just log in each call? How many calls will you be making per minute?

Comment: I cant log in each call, due to session that lasts for hour or so and is also shared with other apps and i only want to catch the lack of session if occurs. to create one.

Comment: And how many calls will you make in one hour?

Comment: This may vary from 1k calls even up to 30k it really depends on time so its really important to make it right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common library for cases like these is Polly;

https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

Its part of the dotnet foundation i believe and is quite commonly used.
You can handle specific exceptions or results and act on that, e.g.

```cs
// Retry once
Policy
  .Handle<SomeExceptionType>()
  .Retry()
```

The logic can get quite complex. For webApi's i usually follow this guide from msdn:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-http-call-retries-exponential-backoff-polly

Comment: This is exactly what i looked for. I cant belive I didnt found it before. Thanks a lot!